# Ajax não funciona em IE6

Tags: ajax

Tenho o Ajax abaixo, que funciona normalmente no Chrome, Firefox (sem erro nenhum no Firebug) e no Opera:

```
/**
  * Função para criar um objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  */
 function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(IEAntigo){

             try{
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(falha){
                 request = false;
             }
         }
     }

     if (!request)
         alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
     else
         return request;
}

//Não executa nada até a execução terminar
var requestActive = false;

function getMotorista() {
    if (requestActive) return;
    requestActive = true;
    // Declaração de Variáveis
    /* Caso for necessário passar mais parametros além do nome
     * basta adicionar uma variável aqui e editar no GET
     */
    var ids = ["rg", "motorista"];
    var registro = document.getElementById("registro").value; //CAMPO QUE VEM DO INDEX.PHP
    var result = document.getElementById("cadastro"); //DIV DE RETORNO DOS DADOS
    var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

    // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
    //result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';
    ids.forEach(function (id) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = 'Aguarde...';
    });

    // Iniciar uma requisição
    // Se for colocar mais variáveis, é aqui. Exemplo: processa.php?txtnome=" + nome + '&admissao=' + admissao
    xmlreq.open("GET", "js/ProcessaMotorista.php?registro=" + registro, true);

    // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de estado
    xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do Oracle
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("registro").focus();
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
        requestActive = false;
    };
    xmlreq.send(null);
}
```

O que acontece e que precisaria fazer ele rodar em um coletor de dados, rodando Windows CE e IE6. Ele não aparece nem erro de nao ter suporte a ajax, simplesmente não faz nada.

Existe alguma coisa nele que poderia fazer para o mesmo funcionar?

Comment: IE6 "Existe alguma coisa nele que funciona"?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert O log de erros. Talvez.

Comment: A burrice do IE é algo que impressiona. Para conseguir fazer essa rotina funcionar tive que passar um parâmetro de segundos+milissegundo dentro do  xmlreq.open. Depois disso funcionou. Vai entender....